# How to avoid perceived flicker during scrolling in Qt?

Tags: performance, qt, drawing, flicker, qpainter

I'm trying use Qt framework(4.7.4) to demonstrate a sliding display in which new pixel data is added to first row of the screen and previous pixels are scrolled one pixel below in every refresh.

It is refreshed 20 times per second and in every refresh, random green points (pixels) are drawn on black background.

The problem is; there is highly noticeable flickers in every refresh. I have researched through the web and optimized my code as much as possible. I tried to use raster rendering  with both QPainter (on QWidget) and QGraphicsScene(on QGraphicsView) and even I tried to use OpenGL rendering  on QGLWidget. However, at the end I have still the same flicker problem.

What may cause this flickering? I begin to suspect that my LCD monitor can not refresh the display for black to green transitions. I have also noticed that if I select a gray background instead of black, there happens no flicker.

Comment: It's highly unusual that you keep the QPainter instance for the pixmap painting across paint events. I think the behavior might even be undefined if you paint the pixmap on another paint device while a QPainter is still open on the pixmap.

Comment: I remember something about double buffering needing to be activated to get a flicker free response (at the cost of memory).

Comment: @RedX, AFAIK, Qt currently supports double buffering and we do not need to write any additional double buffering code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're seeing is purely psychovisual. It's a human defect, not a software defect. I'm serious. You can verify by fixing the value of `x` - you'll still be repainting the entire pixmap on the window, there won't be any flicker - because there is no flicker per se.

The psychovisual flicker occurs when the scroll rate is not tied to the passage of real time. When occasionally the time between updates varies due to CPU load, or due to system timer inaccuracies, our visual system integrates two images and it appears as if the overall brightness is changed.

You've correctly noticed that the perceived flicker is reduced as you reduce the contrast ratio of the image by setting the background to grey. This is an additional clue that the effect is psychovisual.

Below is a way of preventing this effect. Notice how the scroll distance is tied to the time (here: 1ms = 1pixel).

```
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>

static inline int rand(int range) { return (double(qrand()) * range) / RAND_MAX; }

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    float fps;
    qint64 lastTime;
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QBasicTimer timer;
    QElapsedTimer elapsed;
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->timerId() == timer.timerId()) update();
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * ev) {
        qint64 time = elapsed.elapsed();
        qint64 delta = time - lastTime;
        lastTime = time;
        if (delta > 0) {
            const float weight(0.05);
            fps = (1.0-weight)*fps + weight*(1E3/delta);

            if (pixmap.size() != size()) {
                pixmap = QPixmap(size());
                pixmap.fill(Qt::black);
            }
            int dy = qMin((int)delta, pixmap.height());
            pixmap.scroll(0, dy, pixmap.rect());
            QPainter pp(&pixmap);
            pp.fillRect(0, 0, pixmap.width(), dy, Qt::black);
            for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i){
                int x = rand(pixmap.width());
                pp.fillRect(x, 0, 3, dy, Qt::green);
            }
        }
        QPainter p(this);
        p.drawPixmap(ev->rect(), pixmap, ev->rect());
        p.setPen(Qt::yellow);
        p.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50, Qt::black);
        p.drawText(rect(), QString("FPS: %1").arg(fps, 0, 'f', 0));
    }

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), fps(0), lastTime(0), pixmap(size())
    {
        timer.start(1000/60, this);
        elapsed.start();
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you do not scroll the pixmap in-place, but create a second pixmap and use `drawPixmap()` to copy everything but one line from pixmap 1 to pixmap 2 (with the scroll offset). Then continue painting on pixmap 2. After the frame, exchange the references to both pixmaps, and start over.

The rationale is that copying from one memory area to a different one can be optimised more easily than modifying one memory area in-place.

Comment: I forgot to say that it seems there is no performance issue with scrolling the image. It successfully exits from the paintEvent() method under 1 ms (1000fps). The problem seems to be about rendering the pixmap on display. There is no noticable flickers when I use grey color as the background instead of black.

Comment: @Stefan, do you have any measurements to back this up?